# How can I programmatically set button in right corner of edittext?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, android-framelayout, layoutparams

How can I programmatically set button in right corner of `EditText`?

```
FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
lv.addView(fl);

searchTxt = new EditText(this);
fl.addView(searchTxt);

btnSearch = new Button(this);
```

I tried this

```
btnSearch.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
fl.addView(btnSearch);
```

and

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
param.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
fl.addView(btnSearch, param);
```

But the button is still in the left corner.

Comment: why don't you use xml to create the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set layout param for button as following:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams param = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
param.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
```

and set it to button

```
btnSearch.setLayoutParam(param);
f1.addView(btnSearch);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! LinearLayout.LayoutParams replace to FrameLayout.LayoutParams and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `layoutparams` to the LinearLayout to **`Fill_Parent`** in `width`